# How to install mimms on Mac

Tags: macos, installation

(I apologize for my naiveté... I'm new to this whole scripting business)

I am trying to fork a python script from Github. This script has Mimms as a dependency. I am running OSX 10.8.2.

I tried using "apt-get install mimms" but of course this didn't work because OSX doesn't come with apt-get.

I also tried "sudo port install mimms" but I apparently don't have port either.

So I just downloaded mimms directly from [here](http://www.filetransit.com/download.php?id=100663) and sudo mv'd it into /usr/bin/. This is apparently not the right way to do it, because when I try to run the mimms-dependent script, it says "sh: /usr/bin/mimms: Permission denied".

This same problem has prevented me from installing apt-get. (macporter can't locate gcc, which I should have had installed with XCode, but that's a separate issue.)

I feel like I'm missing some obvious step in how to install software that doesn't come with automatic guided installation.

I know this is a ridiculously basic question, but could someone point out my error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org) to get the `port` command and all associated goodness. `apt-get` is for Linux, not Mac. To get `gcc`, install the [XCode Command Line Tools](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/), which is required for MacPorts anyway.

Please, for the love of all that is good, **never** `mv` anything into `/usr/bin` unless you know exactly what you are doing. If you want your own directory for stuff like this on your `$PATH`, run

`mkdir -p ~/bin; echo 'export PATH=$PATH:~/bin' >> ~/.profile; export PATH=$PATH:~/bin`

**exactly** like I typed it (all on one line) and you should be good.

Comment: thanks very  much - I was able to install mimms after getting XCode Command Line tools ( I just had the XCode GUI before apparently).

Comment: @EllenSebastian if you like the answer, please click the check mark next to it to mark your question as answered. Thanks!